# Was Thanos involved in the events of Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, thanos

In the mid-credit scene of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we saw that Thanos puts on the Infinity Gauntlet (without any Infinity Stones) on his hand and said:

> Fine, I’ll do it myself.

Why would he say that in such a way? Someone says such things that way when their men or mercenaries fail to do something (after that they want to step in personally). Was Thanos somehow controlling the Ultron?

Answer (score 19):

It’s possible, but aside from the existence of the post-credits scene, nothing in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (or any other movie) suggests it.

Before *The Avengers*,

> Thanos gave the staff to Loki, in the hope that Loki would recover the Tesseract from Earth and deliver it to him.

And in *Guardians of the Galaxy*

> Thanos was attempting to use Ronan to recover the Power Stone, although Ronan decided to (try to) keep it himself.

I think in the post-credits scene, Thanos was just referring to these two schemes and their failure, rather than anything that happened in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Because if he did influence events in the movie, how? The best theory I’ve seen is that Thanos put some sort of artificial intelligence into the Mind Stone before giving the Sceptre to Loki, presumably in the hope that if Loki failed, someone else would use that intelligence to create a robot that would destroy the Earth.

That seems like a pretty speculative and remote backup plan for getting the Tesseract, especially as the *The Avengers* post-credits scene

> suggests that Thanos didn’t know much about Earth before setting the Chitauri loose.

Note also that

> Ultron makes no attempt to locate the Tesseract in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, and never even mentions it.

(And, as it happens, Thanos wouldn’t have gotten anything even if Ultron succeeded, thanks to Thor taking the Tesseract back to Asgard at the end of *The Avengers*.)

The simpler explanation is Thanos gave the Mind Stone to Loki so that Loki could actually manage to carry out his plan: controlling the minds of Selvig and Hawkeye sure was helpful. A slightly-more-complicated, slightly-more-fun, barely-even-believable explanation is that Loki convinced Thanos to give him the Mind Stone using this reasoning, in hope of keeping it and the Tesseract for himself.

The scene is probably only included at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* because the next Avengers movie is called *Avengers: **Infinity War***, and will thus presumably feature

> Thanos attempting to personally recover all the Infinity McGuffins.

It’s marketing, not plot explanation, like Thor’s hammer in the post-credits scene of *Iron Man 2*.

---

Having pondered this fitfully every night for the last three years, before finally falling into a restless and troubled sleep each time, *Avengers: Infinity War* has finally come out.

> During the movie, Thanos doesn’t mention anything about his actions in *The Avengers*. He certainly uses the Space, Power, Reality and Time stones directly in the movie to further his pursuit of the full set, so he *could* have been using the Mind stone indirectly, as an AI-bootstrap-honeypot-kinda-thing, when embedding it in Loki’s staff (as well as letting Loki use it directly to mind-control people). But there’s no reference to such a plan, or even any reference to Thanos having previously been in possession of the Mind Stone.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'zero indication'. Why could it not refer to a failed scheme in AoU if it also refers to 2 other failed schemes? It's a scene in AoU after all. It could imply that Thanos had something to do with the creation of Ultron (perhaps indirectly) or that he was at least observing the events. There's also the sudden and unexpected awakening of Ultron.

Comment: @Dennis_E: “There's also the sudden and unexpected awakening of Ultron.” But there’s no indication that Thanos caused that, as opposed to your regular Terminator-style “artificial intelligence is born an immediately concludes that humanity must be destroyed” trope. I don’t see anything in the scene itself that suggests a connection to Ultron, other than the fact that it’s the mid-credits scene of the Ultron movie. Thor’s hammer was first seen at the end of Iron Man 2, but Thor didn’t have anything to do with Ivan Vanko.

Comment: Sure, it's just speculation, no direct evidence from AoU, but I've already seen this theory mentioned elsewhere. I have doubts about it myself, but I'm just saying it's out there.

Comment: @Dennis_E: Well you also said there was more than ‘zero indication’ that the theory was correct. That’s what I’m disputing.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you call 'indication' then. They don't know what triggered Ultron. As opposed to 'it just happened', people like to speculate about an explanation. An easy conclusion to jump to is The Mind Stone. And since it came directly from Thanos, 1+1=2. Thanos says "Fine, I'll do it myself", because all his lackeys failed to bring him an Infinity Stone. Because we just saw a movie where again someone (Ultron) fails to hold on to a Stone, that sentence could just as well refer to the events in the movie (which is what this question is about).

Comment: @Dennis_E: oh sure, maybe. I still don’t think that’s supported by the movie. It’s a pretty long game if Thanos thought “Right, I’ll give Loki this staff with the Mind Gem in it so that he can go get me the Space Gem, and if *that* fails then hopefully someone on earth will eventually get the Mind Stone out of the staff *and* use it to make an artificially intelligent robot, which will then lay waste to the earth, allowing me to, er, well, go get the Tesseract out of the debris I guess?” That’s a bit more complicated than 1+1=2.

Comment: I don't believe Thanos planned for Ultron or that Ultron even knew about Thanos. Thanos expected Loki to return the Mind Stone to him. Maybe he took advantage of the situation. Maybe he was just observing. Maybe not. I understand what you're saying. I can also understand why someone would think Thanos was referring to the events in AoU.

Comment: “Maybe he took advantage of the situation.” What, the Ultron situation? Maybe. But again, there’s zero indication of that beyond the existence of the end credits scene, and that’s far more easily explained by “We wanted to start marketing Avengers 3”.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite (to your "more complicated than 1+1=2" comment) The staff itself (presumably thanks to the stone) is what held the mind control powers.  More likely was that it was supposed to affect whoever found it in order to carry out Thanos's wishes, but it was always in containment or held by Stark's Iron Man fist, so it never had a chance.

Comment: Thor does say at the end - just before he leaves for Asgard - that somebody has been manipulating events and playing them for fools. It seems likely that he's talking about Thanos, even if he doesn't know that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: well quite, although I don’t think he’s necessarily saying that Ultron was a manipulated event.

Comment: @Izkata: right, I can understand that. But I don’t see how any of the events in *Age of Ultron* are related to Thanos’s wishes, or caused by the Mind Stone’s mind-control powers (if, indeed, those powers come from the Mind Stone, rather than the staff).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I believe Ronan was using the power stone.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite My point was that even if Thanos did plan on using the Mind Stone and/or Loki's staff as suggested, the plan was (accidentally) totally averted, because no one came into direct contact in order to be affected.  I wasn't talking about Age of Ultron, hence specifying which comment I was replying to

Comment: @Izkata: ah gotcha, sorry, I understand now.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222181/58193). Whilst I share your opinion that it is unlikely, I found an interesting comment from Jackson Sze about it.

Comment: Don't forget that Thanos was the first holder of the scepter. I think he put something in it and hypnotized Scarlett Witch in order to show Tony the memories of the New York attack so that he thinks about creating Ultron. Then, Thanos puts his plan inside Ultron.

Comment: @aminabzz Wanda has plenty of reason to want to mess with Tony’s head of his own accord, and I can’t see how Thanos could put anything inside the sceptre to make some unknown person in the future show another unknown person in the future memories of an event that’s also in the future. I’m also unclear how Thanks could “put his plan” inside Ultron — did Thanos manage to insert a plan into the Mind Stone somehow? And even if that did happen, what plan did Thanos put in there? Provoke a mass extinction? Is that particularly helpful?

Comment: Other than that, sure, great idea.

Answer (score 4):

I think we are not really supposed to know what Thanos plans or what his machinations are. Thanos basically is **the** mastermind. You'll never know what he anticipated and what he'll simply shrug off as an inconvenience.
You're simply not supposed to. He gave the Scepter with the *Mind Stone* to Loki in a gamble to get the *Tesseract*. Which means he had the *Mind Stone* already in his possession **and** was willing to risk it for a second Infinity Stone. One would only do this if one had a backup plan/fail-safe in place. So he didn't care if he lost this Stone or he had a plan to use it to his advantage in case it was lost.

If you think about it, both Avengers movies are about the same thing. The Avengers destroying themselves. In the first movie it's Loki's plan to enrage the Hulk so that he disables/destroys the Avengers. This plan backfires. In the second movie it's Stark's vanity which gives birth to an entity which is capable of destroying the Avengers. Once again the plan backfires if only barely. In the first movie Thanos learns that Earth has a few heroes who will stand up to him and can hinder his plans. His adviser tells him as much. In the second movie something that *might* have been Thanos plan B almost destroys the Avengers along with all of Earth's defenses.

Did Thanos plan for it? Maybe he did. All we know from the post-credit scene is that Thanos is tired of using his lackeys and is now stepping into the ring himself. Which is nothing more than an announcement to the big finale in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd contradict one thing here. Stark's vanity has nothing to do with the rise of Ultron, who emerges because Stark wants to protect the Earth from future invasion. It's fear, not vanity, that results in Ultron.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* director's commentary, Joss Whedon recounts attempts to procure the Infinty Stones:

> Loki failed. Red Skull failed. Ronan failed. Umm, so it's time. Third movie, it's time.

Note that in context, he's discussing Thanos, his schemes, and his imminent entry to the battlefield.  The inclusion of Red Skull is odd, but the lack of mention of Ultron in a list of Thanos' minions indicates that Ultron is not counted among Thanos' attempts to obtain the Infinite Stones.

Comment: The inclusion of Red Skull is a little more interesting after *Infinity War*.

Answer (score 2):

I watched the Ultron integration scene several times. The program doesn't become active until after Tony leaves the lab, JARVIS tells Ultron that he isn't sure what triggered Ultron's awakening. Ultron almost immediately destroys JARVIS. I believe Thanos was monitoring them through the staff and started the whole thing. We know the staff can communicate through space, as Loki did in the first one, so it would make sense, and explain Thanos' statement at the end of the film.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Thanos did have an involvement with the creation of Ultron. Two reasons why:

First, the mid-credits scene suggests that he did. "Fine, I'll do it myself" tells me he was the culprit to the whole thing.

Second, after Ultron makes his first appearance and the Avengers are hashing it out as to what just happened, Mr. Stark says that they did not have a successful interface, and it was never explained how exactly Ultron became successfully interfaced. Even JARVIS didn't know how Ultron came to be.

Comment: There's a bit of supposition in your answer, but you do have it backed up with some facts, so you get an upvote from me. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I'd argue against this. Tony and Bruce say the Mind stone looks like it's thinking. It didn't need their interface, it worked that out itself (we know they had _some_ kind of interface to be able to monitor and project it). The mid-credits scenes were always a preview of what is coming up and I think that's all this was. Thanos had no reason to know what just happened with Ultron. In his story line, another attempt to get an infinity stone had just failed again with Ronan. It just reminded the audience we're still part of that story and built excitement & anticipation for Infinity War.

Answer (score 1):

I've always held the theory that no, Thanos did not have any involvement in *avengers: Age of Ultron*. The best theory I have found to state how Thanos could have had some involvement is [this answer by Spencer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104842/58193) stating that Thanos somehow activated the interface. Probably coupled with Thanos potentially doing something with the Mind Stone. That said I still think Thanos wasn't involved.

However, on reading *The Road to Marvel's Avengers: Endgame - The Art of the Marvel Cinematic Universe* I noticed this interesting little bit from Jackson Sze on the Space Stone and the intro scene to *Avengers: Infinity War*:

> Thanos, the puppeteer behind Loki's attack on New York, has been chasing the Infinity Stone for some time. In the opening sequence of *Avengers: Infinity War*, he finally gets hold of it. "I feel like this scene epitomizes what he said at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*," Senior Concept Illustrator Jackson Sze says. **"When he says, 'I'm going to do it myself.' I think this is like a culmination of that scene where he's actually going for it, as opposed to relying on proxies like Ultron and Loki."**
>
> <sub>*The Road to Marvel's Avengers: Endgame - The Art of the Marvel Cinematic Universe*</sub>

This implies to me that Thanos *did* have some sort of hand in the events that transpired in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. However, beyond this statement there isn't much to back up this theory.

Looking at how Thanos probably wasn't involved in the film's events we have quite a bit of evidence:

- It's not mentioned by anyone in universe with the sole link being the post credits scene.
- The post credits scene [likely takes place on Nidavellir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186532/58193) when Thanos has been having the Gauntlet made for him so he was likely too pre-occupied with that.
- It also probably takes place a lot closer to *Avengers: Infinity War* than we are led to believe but no timeline is given for it.
- Ultron never once mentioned or looked for the Tesseract (of course it was on Asgard), and that was Thanos' plan with Loki, the Mind Stone and the Chitauri.
- Thanos is probably referring to the Loki, Ronan and Gamora schemes failing rather than anything else.
- Out of universe it is of course a set up/marketing for *Avengers: Infinity War* so doesn't have to refer back to *Avengers: Age of Ultron* at all.
- And most importantly: how could he have had an effect on the events of the film really? Whilst I like the aforementioned theory it is very thin with evidence so I doubt it to be true. The same goes for the other theories as well.

Comment: Ultron not mentioning looking for a stone means nothing; Ultron's primary motivation was to show up Stark, and then eliminate humanity. Thanos knew the Avengers were a threat to his plans, so having a proxy to take them out of the picture to he could carry on with what he was doing with less interference was in character with his other actions to that point.

Comment: @KeithMorrison _"Ultron not mentioning looking for a stone means nothing"_: It's ___a___ factor but by far not the only one as my none exhaustive list shows. And sure it's in character but most of the evidence points away from Thanos actually having been involved in that particular plan.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: “Thanos knew the Avengers were a threat to his plans” — I don't think it's clear either way whether he even knew the Avengers existed before the events of *The Avengers*. As a team, they *didn't* exist before Loki showed up on Earth already in possession of the Mind Stone.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: good find, although I think this implies nothing more than Mr Sze was confused by the *Age of Ultron* stinger too.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The thing that gets me is that it isn't just an interview. It is quoted in _The Road to Marvel's Avengers: Endgame - The Art of the Marvel Cinematic Universe_ which, to me, would make it more official.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: yeah, could be. I still haven't heard an explanation of *how* Ultron was a tool of Thanos that makes sense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Me neither.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure everyone remembers this scene:

> Wanda: You took everything from me. 
>  Thanos: I don't even know who you are.

What exactly is Wanda talking about here?

 The obvious answer is Vision; Thanos forced Wanda to kill Vision, then brought him back to life, then killed him again (ouch).

 But Vision is not the only person Wanda lost.

 Wanda lost her brother Pietro too. Who killed him? Ultron.

 This means Wanda could also be referring to Thanos's role in bringing Ultron to life; thereby helping kill Pietro too.

Answer (score -3):

I have a theory:

the base for creating Ultron was taken from Loki's staff, right?

Now think, who gave it to Loki??

What if Thanos 'put' the base for Ultron in the staff, like a Trojan horse, knowing that sooner or later someone will discover it and bring something like Ultron to life? (at the beginning of the film, it seems that HYDRA has discovered this and is making 'bodies' for this AI; which Ultron will claim later as it's main hardware).

After Ultron's rampage and destruction of mankind, Thanos just will have to claim the Mind Stone taking it from Ultron (like what is going to do with The Vision).

so, basically;

- Thanos gives the staff to Loki with the base of a destructive AI (Ultron) on it (in case of Loki's defeat, knowing that humans will keep it and will investigate it) like a Trojan horse.
- HYDRA takes it from SHIELD, finds the base of an AI within the scepter and makes a body for it.
- Stark and the Avengers raid HYDRA's base and take the scepter, Stark discovers this and decides to create the definitive program (due to 'Scarlet Witch's dream') to protect the world, based on the structure of the AI found in the scepter, and gives it a name; ULTRON

It's just a theory, think about it.

Comment: As I mentioned in [a comment discussion with @Dennis_E above](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87325/was-thanos-involved-in-the-events-of-age-of-ultron/87351#comment192284_87351), that’s a pretty long con. Consider also the mid-credits scene of Avengers — the Other is talking to Thanos, and says (and I’m paraphrasing here) “Phew, these humans aren’t the walkover we were promised.” That kind of suggests Thanos didn’t know that much about earth before giving the staff to Loki.

Comment: Plus Ultron didn’t seem to be on a particularly Thanos-centric mission. He just decided to destroy the earth. He never even mentioned obtaining the Tesseract.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite To be fair, even if Ultron *was* being influenced or controlled by Thanos, obtaining the Tesseract probably wouldn't be his mission.  It had been taken to Asgard several years before.

Comment: @Nerrolken: sure, but then what *would* Thanos have wanted Ultron to do? Just generally destroy stuff? Maybe. It still seems remote.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Maybe he just didn't know the teseract was no longer on Earth?

Comment: @Luaan: when you say “he didn’t know the Tesseract was no longer on Earth”, is “he” Thanos, or Ultron?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanos. Ultron probably would be able to find out given his easy access to many secure systems.

Comment: @Luaan: right. Well, when Thanos gave Loki the staff, the Tesseract *was* still on earth, although I don’t think we’ve had any indication whether Thanos knew that or not.

Answer (score -3):

He gave Loki the stone, when Ultron was happening, Thanos was watching to see what developed and take it if events helped him. While not exactly planning it, he was watching in case it helped his plan.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up?