# Are the Infinity Gauntlets from Avengers: Age of Ultron and Avengers: Infinity War the same?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-age-of-ultron

Following the answer to the question: [Has Marvel commented on the extra Infinity Gauntlet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64885/has-marvel-commented-on-the-extra-infinity-gauntlet/87873#87873), Feige [confirmed](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Big-Secret-Behind-Infinity-Gauntlet-According-Marvel-Kevin-Feige-71192.html) that:

> "There are two different gloves. That was not Odin’s vault that you see at the end."

Assuming what Hela said is true, the Gauntlet in Odin's vault is fake. However, by the looks of it, Thanos' Gauntlet in the post-credits of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and the fake Gauntlet in the vault look exactly the same (*images below*).

[image: Fake Gauntlet in Odin's vault] [image: Gauntlet from AoU scene]
 <sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>

In addition, the Infinity Gauntlet in *Avengers: Infinity War* is totally different from what we see in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

[image: Thanos with the Gauntlet in IW]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

So, are the Gauntlets from *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (post credits scene) the same? If yes, is there an out-of-universe explanation as to why the two Gauntlets were designed differently?

If they're not the same, then was the Gauntlet in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* a fake?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're supposed to be the same, except that the one from Infinity War (and Endgame) has been redone to make it look less shiny. Shiny things are hard to film with CGI because you have to replace the image *and* the reflection

Comment: @Valorum look at the fingers, the one in *IW* has some sort of patterns while the others don't. also, the red coloring is not seen in *IW*'s gauntlet. Maybe I'm wrong but I captured as many images as I could but none of them seem to show any sort of resemblance.

Comment: Sure. But they're supposed to be the same. Props often change from one film to another based on use-case

Comment: Since Joss Whedon directed *AoU* and the Russos were responsible for the Infinity saga, I thought there might be some sort of discontinuity between them

Comment: Nah; https://www.screengeek.net/2018/05/09/why-thanos-looked-different-in-avengers-infinity-war/

Comment: "Thanos' Gauntlet in the post-credits of Avengers: Age of Ultron and the fake Gauntlet in the vault look exactly the same"...Except one is a right hand, the other is a left hand, so not the same?

Comment: @Darren Yessir, but I meant from the design point of view. Also, I said they look the same, i didn't say they are the same :p

Answer (score 5):

The two Infinity Gauntlets, from the post-credits scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and *Avengers: Infinity War*, do have some physical differences to them. This would mean they are likely not the same Gauntlet. However, from [my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/214073/58193) we see that the post-credits scene probably took place on Nidavellir.

> The *Avengers: Age of Ultron* post-credits scene saw Thanos claiming the Infinity Gauntlet and saying, "Fine, I'll do it myself," after Ultron had failed to wipe out humanity. However, in *Avengers: Infinity War*, it was revealed the Mad Titan had forced Eitri to forge the gauntlet for him. With Eitri's Nidavellir home having been under the protection of Asgard, many fans claim it's impossible for him to have given Thanos the gauntlet so long ago. Joe Russo, director of Avengers: Infinity War, has explained to ComicBook.com that the post-credits scene did, in fact, take place on Nidavellir.
>
> "I think that it would be connected to Eitri," Joe Russo said. "I think that clearly he is the one who forged the gauntlet and Thanos had the gauntlet at that point in time. It's been a while since any of the Asgardians have interacted with Eitri and his people."
>
> <sub>[ComicBook, 'Avengers: Infinity War' Directors Explain That 'Ultron' MCU Plot Hole](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/07/avengers-infinity-war-ultron-gauntlet-plot-hole-explained/)</sub>

As such that gives two probably, very similar, possibilities to explain this:

1. The Gauntlet wasn't quite finished or needed some ever so slight touching up after the scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* before we see it in *Avengers: Infinity War*.
2. The Gauntlet we see in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is actually one of the prototypes that Eitri makes.

Of the two I think the second is probably the most likely. After all, we do see a prototype Gauntlet in *Avengers: Infinity War* when Thor, Rocket, and Groot all initially get to Nidavellir.

[image: Prototype gauntlet on Nidavellir]

Out of universe, though, of course, Thanos was re-designed himself ever so slightly for *Avengers: Infinity War* and so refining the Gauntlet was probably also part of that as explained by "Matt Aitken, VFX supervisor on Infinity War for Weta"

> "Those sequences in Guardians is where we see him most clearly in the previous MCU films. It was a wonderful freedom to not have to match that exactly. I think it's one thing to have a Thanos who in those scenes was definitely more stylized, holed up for those short beats that he was in those films. But when he had to be the lead character and hold film and appear in hundreds and hundreds of shots, it was great to have the latitude to refine his look, to make his facial appearance more natural, so he's definitely more detailed and has a more natural shape to his face, to his lips, to his brow, his nose, and all those details we're talking about in terms of the blemishes and the pores and the stubble. If we'd been confined to those earlier iterations, it would have been too much of a limitation, I think, so that was never an issue. Right from the start, Marvel recognized the need to go to the next version of Thanos, and we were never asked to match that earlier version at all."
>
> <sub>[Screen Rant, Why Thanos' Design Changed So Much For Avengers: Infinity War](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-thanos-design-change)</sub>

Comment: “we do see a prototype Gauntlet in Avengers: Infinity War when Thor, Rocket and Groot all initially get to Nidavellir” — isn't that the mould for the actual Infinity Gauntlet?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Huh, interesting... didn't think of that. I'm not sure how such a mould like that would work though. You'd have to pour the metal inside and then hollow it out afterwards?

Comment: Or it's dipped in the metal, and then... somehow removed afterwards? Could be a prototype mould or something. I dunno man, I'm not a metalworker. Totally could be a prototype gauntlet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah I'm no metalworker either but I suppose that _might_ be able to work. I'll just assume it was a prototype or a "design phase" Gauntlet. It is a very basic look different to the actual Infinity Gauntlet.